# Best Way to Convert HTML and jQuery Mobile into a cross platform app?

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile

I write this question with pure frustration. Let me first explain what my app does:

- The App simply just pulls and updates data on a server. That is it, I
  don't look to do anything else except this. i.e I wont be using the camera or the contacts list - nothing just working with a server and an API.

What I wish to do in the future:

- Simply Have Facebook JS SDK functionality.
- Android Push Notifications

I have now for a good few weeks been using Phonegap to take my HTML and JQuery Mobile code and to get it to run on Android.

BUT

In the Phonegap I have add many issues, simply creating a Phonegap project was a mission. The Facebook Plugin for Phonegap is appalling (it just doesn't work).

I'm now looking to the community for some guidance and help on this subject. Im hoping that Phonegap is not the only way out? Please any help would be really really appreciated!!

Comment: Phonegap is a pretty simple way to implement HTML and jQuery mobile. Normally the issues I found were due to jQuery mobile. If you are having issues with phonegap then I think you should reconsider your implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for an alternative to PhoneGap, and your app is fairly simple, you could simply create an Android, iOS app with a WebView (browser) component, through which your app will be delivered.

Or, even simpler, create a bookmark of your app's website URL.

In both of these scenarios, you'll only need to trouble yourself with the issues of jQuery and other libraries you want to integrate.

Comment: That's not a bad suggestion although not a favorable implementation due to webview performance but applicable to OP. Good thinking.

Comment: Thank you! I just had a read on the Android docs and this seems to hopefully do what I an looking for!!

Comment: webview performance is usually poor, and *almost* always worse than native. A few pros for webview approach is: cost, speed of delivery, and simplicity. Otherwise, I would just recommend *pure native* if possible.